# Текст из адресной строки в поле

Tags: строки, парсер

Здравствуйте! 
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, не пойму как это реализовать.

Есть к примеру 4 поля на сайте при редактирование материала.
Адрес страницы такой: `http://site.ru/edit?url=site.ru/doc1&title=Тут+назваие+статьи&description=Описание&user=Admin`

Как из адресной строки разложить все по полям?

title - в поле с id "title"

url - в поле с id "url" и т.д.

Есть такой код:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function () { 
if(location.search) { 
var title = location.search.toString(); 
$('input').val(decodeURIComponent(title.split('?title=').join(''))); 
} 
} 
); 
</script>
```

Comment: Код в студию...

Comment: поправил вопрос

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$string = 'http://site.ru/edit?url=site.ru/doc1&title=Тут+назваие+статьи&description=Описание&user=Admin';
$query = explode('?',$string);
if(!array_key_exists(1,$query)){
    die('Params no found.');
}
$query = $query[1];
$params = array();
$attrs = explode('&',$query);
foreach($attrs as $attr){
    $a = explode('=',$attr);
    if(array_key_exists(1,$a)){
        $params[$a[0]] = $a[1];
    }else{
        $params[$a[0]] = null;
    }
}
var_dump($params);
```

Comment: спасибо большое. только я, глупый, забыл указать, что на jquery или js можно такое?